# Incorrect response from Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") and Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") with VR headset

Tags: unity-game-engine

Usually the call to Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") and Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") works fine, but when I put on my Windows Mixed Reality VR headset, the axis return values based on the screen position, instead of the intended response, which should be the change in the mouse's x/y position since the last frame.

Is there a way to get around this? Apparently a team member of mine also has this issue on his laptop even though he doesn't have a VR headset.

I have reproduced this issue in a new project, so it shouldn't be an issue with my project settings.

Comment: the Mouseposition will always be `x,y` **on the screen** .. so it is allways depend on the screen movement .. is there a special reason why you want to use a mouse in VR? Usually you would use some controller device and rather optain a 3D position maybe relative to the head instead ...

Comment: @derHugo Well, the game we are making is not a VR game, but if you were to plug in and enable a Windows Mixed Reality headset, the `Input` API functions as described above.

Comment: Could you post the code of how exactly you are using it?

Comment: @derHugo I am just calling the Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") and Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") methods. Even if I open a brand new project and Debug.Log their values, I have the same issue.